# On the definition of cofinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having some difficulty comprehending the definition of a cofinite set. I am seeking confirmation of whether my understanding is correct and some clarification on the definition.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Other_examples) provides the following definition:

**Definition:** A cofinite subset of a set $X$ is a subset $A$ whose complement in $X$ is a finite set. In other words, $A$ contains all but finitely many elements of $X$.

Based upon my understanding, I have come up with a definition I believe is equivalent.

**Definition':** Suppose there are two sets, $X$ and $A$ where $A \subset X$. $A$ is cofinite in $X$ if $A^c \cap X$ is finite, where the $c$ superscript denotes the complement.

Comment: Two related questions: 1) How is $A^c \cap X$ different from "the complement of $A$ in $X$"?  2) $A^c$ is defined with respect to what universal set?

Comment: In class-set theories, $A^c$ is understood to be the class of all sets not in $A$, which works perfectly well here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's fine.

Note that $A^c\cap X=X\setminus A$, which may be simpler to read.

Comment: Another advantage of using $X \setminus A$ is that it makes sense even when $A \nsubseteq X$.

Comment: How does $A^c\cap X$ not make sense if $A \nsubseteq X$?

Comment: Oh, you probably meant the first definition. But one generally speaks of cofinite subsets, not cofinite intersecting sets or some such...